# What happens when I remove someone from a Trello board?

Tags: trello, delete

I'm about to remove members from my Trello board and the organization they and the board belong to. The members have been active in creating cards, being assigned to them and making comments, etc.

I would like their profile or at least their name connected to the actions they made on the board. So for example that a comment from them on a card is still visible and their name is attached to it.

**What happens to these 'profiles' inside cards?** I guess they are unassigned from cards. But what more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will be unassigned from cards, and that's about it. Their actions will be preserved, as will the fact that they performed the actions.

Comment: [Official documentation](http://help.trello.com/article/779-removing-a-member-from-a-board) for reference.